# Image not updating in WPF view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, flipview

I have created one wpf application and created a flipview control in it while rendering I have used the following code

```
<controls:FlipView x:Name="flipViewControl"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Product.Images}"
                   SelectedIndex="0"
                   SelectionChanged="flipViewControl_SelectionChanged">
    <controls:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"
                   Stretch="Fill" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</controls:FlipView>
```

The `product.Images` is an observable collection of image Uri's. When I have changed the product.Images from the code behind the View is not updating.

```
private ObservableCollection<Uri>  images;

public ObservableCollection<Uri>  Images
{
    get { return images; }
    set
    {
        images = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

 public void SetImages(IEnumerable<Uri> images)
        {
            Images.Clear();
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                Images.Add(image);
                RaisePropertyChanged("Product");
            }
        }
```

It still shows the first image.What will be the reason?

Comment: Show product.Images definition and how you change it.

Comment: Are you sure there are more then 1 elements in images list?

Comment: Are the new Uris different from the old ones, or are you probably replacing existing image files and re-using their Uris?

Comment: I am proving a point with these questions so don't disregard them .

1) What is the DataContext ?
2) Is Product a property in that DataContext ?
3) In what class is the Images property posted above ?